# how to make sure the apps can only be downloaded by iphone but ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, download

I have developed some apps by xcode.How to make sure my apps can only be downloaded by iphone user in apple store but ipad user?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the targeted device to iPhone only.
Select you project in Xcode, Go to Info-->Deployment Info--->Device, set it to iPhone.